# Is it possible to set the marker edge alpha in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, say I want to plot with `color='None'` but `markeredgecolor='mediumseagreen'` with the edges having `alpha=0.5`.  Is that possible?

Comment: You just have to pass the color in as an RGBA tuple

Comment: I'm not sure I agree this is a duplicate.  There are `kwargs` like `markeredgecolor` and `markeredgewidth`...so I was curious if there was an equivalent to `markeredgealpha`.  That would be very convenient in situations where the `markeredgecolor` is being set as something other than RGB.  I.e. in my example, I'd like 50% opacity mediumseagreen.  But I don't know the RGB value of mediumseagreen off the top of my head...

Comment: Can't argue with that.  Maybe I'll do a small pull request to make the `markeredgealpha` kwarg that I'm pining for.

Comment: just to clarify a couple typos:  `matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter().to_rgba('mediumseagreen', alpha=0.5)`

Comment: The colors module has a singleton instance of `ColorConverter` called `colorconvertor` so I would not say it is a typo.

Comment: You are totally right!  So sorry for the misunderstanding.  I missed the `colorConverter = ColorConverter()` in the source.

Comment: Want to suggest this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If @tcaswell doesn't want to post an answer, you are free to post and accept one yourself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**As answered in the comments:**

Either pass the color as an RGBA tuple or get the RGBA value from `colorConverter`:

```
matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgba('mediumseagreen', alpha=.5)
```